# Niece, or Sister-in-law?

Tags: terminology

My brother recently adopted a seventeen year old girl, and she’s one of my favorite nieces, but I’ve reached a dilemma. I’m marrying her older sister, and now I don’t know what to call her.
She’s technically my niece, and my sister-in-law. What do I do??

Comment: She is your niece by adoption, which is not how most nieces are acquired: however she will be your sister in law by marriage which is how sisters in law are always acquired. So the more standard relationship will be sister in law. However both relationships will exist and which relationship you use will depend on your own preference and the context in which you are discussing her. You will usually refer to her by name because family members and close friends will know all about the relationship and you can always introduce her to others as your relative and expand later if necessary.

Comment: On behalf of the community, where it's too easy to miss the bigger picture, Mazel Tov :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call her both, because she **is** both. Though alternating between the two could be a bit abnormal, but then again, this is a site for grammar and not discussion of social norms. But you'll have to consider the context for the situation where you're referring to her. In some contexts, her being your niece is the most relevant factor, while in other, her being your sister-in-law is.

Comment: You added this answer while I was adding my comment above. We seem to have said pretty much the same thing, which probably means we're both right.

Comment: Yes, so it seems.